# When is $\cos(\pi k/n)$ , $\sin(\pi k/n)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[1/\sqrt{p}]$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

For which rationals $ k/n $ do we have
$$
\cos(\pi k/n) , \sin(\pi k/n) \in \mathbb{Z}[1/\sqrt{p}] 
$$
where $ p $ is prime?

Certainly when $ k/n=0,1/2,1,3/2 $ we have
$$
 \cos(\pi k/n)=1,0,-1,0 \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
and
$$
 \sin(\pi k/n)=0,1,0,-1 \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
If we pick the prime $ p=2 $ then we also have the rational values $ k/n= 1/4,3/4,5/4,7/4 $ for which
$$
 \cos(\pi k/n)=1/\sqrt{2},-1/\sqrt{2},-1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Z}[1/\sqrt{2}] 
$$
and
$$
 \sin(\pi k/n)=1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2},-1/\sqrt{2},-1/\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Z}[1/\sqrt{2}] 
$$
Are there any other rational values $ k/n $ for the prime $ p=2 $? Are there any other rational values $ k/n $ for other primes $ p $?

Comment: This would imply that $\mathbb Z[1/\sqrt{p},\sqrt{-|}]$ contains a primitive $n/\gcd(n,k)$th root of unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\gcd(n,k)=1.$ This would imply that $\mathbb Z\left[1/\sqrt{p},\sqrt{-1}\right]$ contains $\zeta =e^{i\pi k/n}$. The degree of $\mathbb Q[1/\sqrt p,\sqrt{-1}]$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $4.$

If $k$ is even, then $\zeta=e^{i\pi k/n}$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity. If $k$ is odd, it is a primitive $2n$th root of unity.

So the degree of $\mathbb Q[\zeta]$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $\phi(n)$ if $k$ is even and $\phi(2n)$ if $k$ is odd.

But we know $\mathbb Q[\zeta]$ is a subfield of $\mathbb Q[1/\sqrt p,\sqrt{-1}].$ So this means, at minimum you require:

$$\begin{align}\phi(n)\mid 4&\quad k\text{ even}\\
\phi(2n)\mid 4&\quad k\text{ odd}\end{align}$$

That will greatly reduce the number of possible values for $n.$

So, for $k$ even, the only possible $n$ must be odd, and that gives $n=1,3$ or $5.$

For $k$ odd, $n=2,3,4,5,6.$

These are necessary, not sufficient conditions, so you need to check these values, but we've reduced it to a small set of possibilities.

---

In particular, $\mathbb Q\left[1/\sqrt 3,\sqrt{-1}\right]$ contains $e^{i\pi/3},$ but $\mathbb Z\left[1/\sqrt 3,\sqrt{-1}\right]$ does not. So you really have to check the cases.

Comment: Thanks! For $ n=3 $ the roots of unity $ e^{i \pi k /3} $ are well know to variations of $ \frac

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira Not clear what you were about to write, but for $n=3,$ the problem is the $1/2,$ not the $\sqrt{-3}.$

Comment: haha I'm so sorry I accidentally pressed enter then went back to editing the comment then got distracted editing my answer to a question about finite subgroups of the unitary group. Anyway all I was going to say was exactly what you are saying. $ n=3 $ is known and the $ 1/2 $ is the problem . For $ k $ even and $ n=5 $ it seems that the $ 1/2 $ (or rather $ 1/4 $ ) is again a problem see http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2008/01/de-moivre-5-7-solvable-by-radicals.html and in general seems like you needs powers of $ 1/2 $ for all those values of $ n$ so that completes your proof basically